# References needed for Theorem

Tags: homological-algebra

I am studying homological algebra by my self from Basic Homological algebra by M.Scott Osborne , I am having trouble to understand Theorem 3.9 page 56.

[image]

My question is where can I find this Theorem in another reference like Rotman or others.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: I tried to add the theorem to the question. Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: This is used in the book to show the "balancing of Tor". One possible alternative reference with a similar proof is Weibel, "An introduction to homological algebra", section 2.7.

Comment: (There is a better, elegant way to get the balancing of Ext and Tor, but it's slighly outside of the context of your particular textbook; it uses the definition of derived functors as "universal $\delta$-functors".)

Comment: Thanks, Don ,which text book or notes online can I find it

Comment: For instance, see p. 15 here: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W14/Tor.pdf